# roblem with ROS control and Gazebo

Tags: ros, robotics, gazebo-simu

I have a problem with controlling a URDF that I exported from SolidWorks. (Ubuntu 16.04 , Kinetic, Gazebo 7.x) I followed this tutorial and I wanted to implemented on my robot. All the controllers are starting correctly so as the Gazebo simulation also the Node publish the data correctly I have checked it with echo-ing the topic and with different values for the data. Is there a chance not working because the PID values ?

All the transmissions look like this :

```xml
<transmission name="tran1">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="Joint_1">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="motor1">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
</transmission>
```

The controller is like this (for all joints) :

```
joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 50
joint1_position_controller:
    type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
    joint: Joint_1
    pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
```

And I have this node:

```py
    rospy.init_node('ArmMovement')
    pub1=rospy.Publisher("/rrbot/joint1_position_controller/command",Float64,queue_size=10 )
    rate = rospy.Rate(50)
    ArmCor1= Float64()
    ArmCor1.data=0
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      pub1.publish(ArmCor1)
      rate.sleep()
```

Part of URDF for the Joint_1:

```xml
<joint name="Joint_1" type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 0 -0.008"
      rpy="1.5708 0 0" />
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="Link_1" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit
      lower="0"
      upper="3.14"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
</joint>
```

Comment: What does the [rostopic list](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_list) console command return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help, it actually work after your comments. 
This was my Joint_1 :

```
 <joint name="Joint_1" type="revolute">
 <origin
 xyz="0 0 -0.008"
 rpy="1.5708 0 0" />
<parent link="base_link" />
<child link="Link_1" />
<axis
xyz="0 1 0" />
<limit
 lower="0"
 upper="3.14"
 effort="0"
 velocity="0" />
</joint>
```

I changed the limit section to this :

```
<limit
lower="0"
upper="3.14"
effort="2"
velocity="2.0" />
```

I have other problems like a very annoying shiver (that comes from effort value I think) but It is not for this topic.